# How to transmit modulated voice over a call in Android?

Tags: android, phone-call

I want to know in Android it is possible to transmit modulated voice like [Ultra voice changer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kimusoft.voice_changer_chipmunk) app does during a call. I have searched a lot but I only got results for how to change voice after recording. So, please reply me that is it possible to transmit changed voice at a time of call in Android.

Comment: Didn't you answer your question yourself "is it possible to do ... like another app DOES"?

Comment: Actually that app change voice which is recorded but i want to change voice during a call its just an example that i want to do something like this app does but at the time of a call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems not possible. According to this [XDA-Post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=27893384) "The calling screen is built within the phone". You can replace a dialer, but are not able to intercept the voice spoken during a call. 
I cannot find any official API from android, which would make it possible to write your own "calling" App (which means record voice and send it).

Comment: is it possible to do so on regular call i have read that it may be possible using voip service but i want to make this work on GSM service

Comment: please, I' can hardly understand what you want: `is it possible to do so on regular call` As I already stated: NO! `i have read that it may be possible using voip service` please provide links for others to check it. Of course you are able to write a voip app (like Google Voice) because its nothing more than standard internet-protocols. But again: as I stated this is *NOT* possible for GSM. There is *_NO_* Api for gsm voice calls!

Comment: Would it be possible to create a custom rom/kernel with that capability?

Comment: @Urgo of course, you can do that. Its the ROM that provides calling mechanisms, so one is able to change all of it. There is also a chance to use XPosedFramework http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/framework-xposed-rom-modding-modifying-t1574401 on a standart (rooted) rom to change internal API calls and redirect them over to your Xposed-module

Answer (score 1):

The GSM full rate speech codec operates at 13 kbits/s and uses a Regular Pulse Excited (RPE) codec - This means that the microphone and speech detection in GSM is optimised for transmission across a Time Division Multiplexed 'digital' channel that is then modulated across the air interface using GMSK, a continuous-phase frequency-shift keying modulation scheme.

Noises other than the 'average' speech pattern are heavily distorted (or suppressed) - For instance DTMF (tones) are not well received on a device, and must be transmitted by the network core, but tones designed for the hearing impaired work well. Voice is shaped (filtered) on entry to the codec (microphone design) for best codec detection and reproduction at the other end.

In summary - It is not possible to 're-modulate' across the GSM system, because the entry point is not a radio (air interface), or even access the GSM digital frame. Your only access for a voice call is the GSM codec which is expecting a voice in a confined audio spectrum.

Answer (score 0):

I know there are apps that act like voice changer where they change your voice and transmit that thru gsm voice. Maybe you can make an app that takes the voice then modulate it to something like phase shift keying or digital radio monodiale like what hams used for digital vhf, hf, dpmr, mototrbo radio communication and transmit the audio thru gsm voice channel then demodulate it back to normal voice but instead of straight forward modulation demodulation you can add pgp, aes, pre shared keys, blowfish or whatever encryption you like. I'm also intrested to see a project like this.

I think it would also be great if we could use this to transmit data thru voice gsm channel like the 56k dial up modems in the past instead of the gprs data channel allowing you to make data connection to other cellphone to transfer files without incurring additional data charges which is really good for subscribers with unlimited call plans.

See reference:

http://freedv.org/tiki-index.php

http://www.aprs.org